# Movie Identification 70's-90's alien movie

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I've been looking for a movie for some 2 years now but haven't been able to find it. Here's what I remember:

- Aliens were kinda red boulder like things kind of like Fantastic Four's "The Thing", except more red
- They were trying to find a male dna sample for reproduction or something like that
- There were 2 aliens - 1 female and 1 male
- The female lured the men out and they had sex then she or he killed them
- Scenes:

  - They were in their rock form testing dna and he said "this sample isn't the right one"
  - She pretended to be a hitch-hiker and the driver said "you shouldn't ride with strangers", to which she replied "I know" and they start getting it on up against a boulder then she breaks his neck

**What is the title of this movie?**